# Making a Discord bot delete a chat once a react was pressed

Tags: javascript, discord.js

Trying to make a discord bot to delete the last response when the react button was pressed by the user. (BOT has all permissions granted).

```
    const botResponse = result.data.choices[0].message;
    const botMessage = await message.reply(botResponse);
    botMessage.react(''); // Add a resend reaction to the bot's response

    const filter = (reaction, user) => reaction.emoji.name === '' && user.id === message.author.id;
    const collector = botMessage.createReactionCollector({ filter, time: 60000, max: 1 });

    collector.on('collect', async (reaction) => {
        await botMessage.delete();
        conversationLog.pop();
        message.channel.send('Bot response deleted!');
    });
```

For some reason I cant make this to work. Bot works properly except for this part.No error in VSC as well. Bot just wont do anything once react was pressed.

For context: This a chat GPT discord bot and im trying to make a function where when a user press the  react button, the bot will delete that chat and send a new response.

If you guys has a better way of coding it, it will be a huge help. Thanks in advance,

Comment: Which intents are you specified?